# can we use php tags inside html attributes?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have stored image paths in a mysql table. for the following code the image does not load.

```
<?php 
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
        mysql_select_db('ratesl');
        $result = mysql_query("select name,rating_count,image,average from infos join ratings on infos.id = ratings.p_id order by average DESC ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            $img_path = "img/".$row->image; ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:15px"> <img src=<?php $img_path; ?>/> </td>
                <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                 <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->rating_count; ?></td>
                <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->average; ?></td>
            </tr>
       <?php } ?>
```

althogh $img_path contains the values from the database table, the src value for the img is left blank. what is the issue here?

Comment: The issue is... you are missing "echo" before `$img_path`. How do you expect PHP prints this variable? Look what you did in those rows bellow. You didn't forget echoing other values...

Comment: print_r the results of your query & check if url of image is being fetched from database or not.

Comment: yes its possible, just echo it like what you did inside the `td` tags

Comment: okay. that was the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code missing quotation and echo ..

```
<img src=<?php $img_path; ?>/>
        ^^^   ^^^          ^^^
```

you need quotation

```
<img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>"/>
        ^^^                      ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
<img src="<?php echo $img_path?>" />
```

(Dont forget the quotation marks :) )

Answer (score 0):

Forget to echo the $img_path

```
<?php 
            mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
            mysql_select_db('ratesl');
            $result = mysql_query("select name,rating_count,image,average from infos join ratings on infos.id = ratings.p_id order by average DESC ");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                $img_path = "img/".$row->image; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding:15px"> <img src=<?php echo $img_path; ?>/> </td>
                    <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                     <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->rating_count; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:15px"> <?php echo $row->average; ?></td>
                </tr>
           <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You should also quote the src attribute in your img tag: `<img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src=<?php echo $img_path; ?>
```